# nesting limit to elasticsearch type=object

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a nesting limit/level how deep you can nest objects in Elasticsearch?

Some structures currently are 3 levels deep, e.g.: `x.y.z`, hence my question about the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no limits as far as nesting goes. Basically, any valid JSON document can be stored in ES.

The only limit that you could encounter could be when retrieving a deeply-nested document that you'd like to parse with a language-specific parser, such as PHP's [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which by default only supports 512 levels, though you can adjust it.

But if you reach that many levels you probably need to rethink your document design ;-)

Another limitation that you need to consider is that two fields with the same name at any different levels, will need to [have the exact same mapping](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring) (i.e. the same field type). Concretely, you cannot have `x.y.z` being 123 (an `integer`) and `a.b.c.d.z` being "cat" (i.e. a `string`)